# Where can I modify the default damage system on UDK

Tags: udk, scripting

I want to make a custom damage system on my game but I can't find the function that handles it...

I looked on Actor.uc but the only thing I've found is the event TakeDamage, but there's nothing on it that actually deals the damage.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TakeDamage is the ticket. Pawn::TakeDamage is where the default damage system for characters and vehicles is located.